# Given a perimeter and a number of edges what shape has the greatest area?

Tags: geometry

So given a perimeter of total length $L$ and $n$ edges that the shape must have what is the shape that maximizes the area?

The answer is probably a regular $n$-gon with lengths of $L/n$ but how do I prove it?

The motivation for the problem: I was thinking about how difficult it is to prove that the circle is the "best" in terms of area and why it's so difficult and this question naturally arises.

Comment: You're right about the regular $n$-gon.  See p. 529 of "The Evolution of the Isoperimetric Problem" by Viktor Blåsjö (American Mathematical Monthly, June-July 2005): https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/blasjo526.pdf for a proof.

Comment: Thanks. I saw it